# how to ship logs files from my springboot pod running on EKS to ELK

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, elk

I am running my pods on EKS cluster. The containers are based on Spring boot application. How to ship the logs files from spring boot application using filebeats to Elasticsearch on AWS? I do not see any article on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application logs everything to stdout, the idea is to install Filebeat as a Daemonset on the EKS cluster, so a pod on every node.
Then configure Filebeat mounting the docker folder, so it can read the logs and send the data to ElasticSearch (or Logstash).

Elastic docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/running-on-kubernetes.html

Comment: My applications logs to a specific location `/var/log/app.log`

Comment: I recommend to log to stdout, or both file and stdout, it is easier in a Kubernetes environment. As a workaround, you can share a volume with the logs between your app and Filebeat.